# Sum elements based on a predicate

Tags: scala, dictionary, iteration

Consider this code:

```
val definedFields: Int = datMap.values.map(x => if (x.isDefined) 1 else 0).sum
```

datMap is a Map where values have type Option[Something_that_has_isDefined]

- Does map().sum iterates 2 times or does it build expression tree and
  execute once.
- Is there a way to make is shorter? One way to do it is to fold it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is method `count` that counts the number of elements which satisfy a predicate.

```
datMap.values.count{_.isDefined}
```

> Does map().sum iterates 2 times or does it build expression tree and execute once.

With regular collection, like `List` you'll get an intermediate collection after `map`. With lazy collection like `Stream` or any `view` you'll get wrapper after `map`.

See also [Scala’s Collections Library/Views](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/views.html)

Comment: Why count{_.isDefined) not count(_.isDefined) ?

Comment: @lukas I prefer to use `{}` with lambdas. Just to stress out that I'm creating a function.

Comment: @lukas, the other reason: you can't use pattern matching without `{}`. In your case: `datMap.count{ case (_, v) => v.isDefined}`.

Answer (score 3):

Consider `flatten` and `flatMap` like this,

```
datMap.values.flatten.size
```

where `flatten` trims out non defined values, or in one pass,

```
datMap.flatMap(_._2).size
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways, one would be with `fold` as you said:

```
scala> List(Some(1), None, Some(3), None, Some(8))
res0: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(1), None, Some(3), None, Some(8))

scala> res0.foldLeft(0)(_ + _.map(_ => 1).getOrElse(0))
res1: Int = 3
```

Using `fold` allows one iteration, mapping and then using `sum` uses two iterations, one for `map` and the other for `sum` since the latter is implemented using `foldLeft`:

```
def sum[B >: A](implicit num: Numeric[B]): B = foldLeft(num.zero)(num.plus)
```